# SQL: List all entries for a foreign key, acquired in same query

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I need to make a really simple DB in an android application (I'm using SQLite) and have no idea how to make this query.

Let's say I have these two tables, linked together with the `locationid` from the first:

```
CREATE TABLE locations
(
  locationid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  floor INTEGER,
  room INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE entries
(
  entryid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title TEXT,
  summary TEXT,
  date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY(location) REFERENCES locations(locationid)
);
```

How do I construct the following query: get all rows from table "entries" for room 308, floor 3?

Comment: This is a very basic SQL query, that involves a `join` and a `where` clause.  If you are going to use SQL effectively, you should take some time to study and practice the basics.

Comment: The `create table entries (...` is invalid because it doesn't define a column `location` yet it tries to make that column a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE locations = (SELECT locationid
                   FROM locations
                   WHERE room=308
                     AND floor=3)
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM entries e
JOIN locations l ON e.locations = l.locationid
WHERE l.room = 308
  AND l.floor = 3
```

Comment: The second one is wrong (will yield multipe e tuples if more than one reference to locationid is present in locations)

Comment: Partially Agree with @wildplasser. I assumed that table will have no repeat entries.

Comment: The first one will fail if there is more than one location with `room = 308 and floor = 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM locations l INNER JOIN entries e
ON l.locationid = e.location
WHERE l.floor = 3
 AND  l.room  = 308
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple JOIN statement :

```
 select
    locations.*,      -- suppress this if only entries table are needed
    entries.*         -- you can select only date and title instead of everything
 from locations
 join entries
    on entries.location=locations.locationid      -- using your foreign key
 where
    locations.room=308                            -- first condition
    and locations.floor=3                         -- second condition
 ;
```

You could use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN if you want to retrieve informations on the room (for example) even if no data are linked within entries table.

Final word : I'm pretty sure the answer was already here on stackoverflow and on the web too.